# why is the derivative equal to zero here?

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

In this [MIT open course video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15HVevXRsBA&list=PL4C4C8A7D06566F38) Denis Auroux said that
given a function $f(x, y)$ and a restriction level
surface $g(x, y) = c$, for any vector $u$ tangent to
this surface $g=c$, we must have:

$$
\left.\frac{df}{ds} \right|_{u} = 0,
$$

where $s$ is a parameter such that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{pmatrix}
+ s
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

making the position vector
$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
$
moving the direction of $u$.

I am a little suspicious of this conclusion. Suppose $g$ is
just a plane $x - y = 0$ and $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$, I can
imagine a lot of vectors on the surface can be found as
counter examples. But I am not so confident of my own
reasoning so far. Can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phrase "restriction level surface". Could you define it? Were $f$ and $g$ defined to have any sort of relation to each other?

Comment: The function you define is not constant on that plane!

Comment: An equation of the form $g(x, y) = c$ defines a level *curve.*  If you want a level *surface*, then you can consider the set of $(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R}^3$ such that $g(x, y, z) = c$.  (This set might contain singularities, but it *can* produce a surface).

Comment: @Hurkyl Denis explained it in the video, not sure the words are exact. But basically it's a min/max problem with some restriction. For example, find the extreme values of $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$, given $xy = 3$.

Comment: @SammyBlack he justs omits the $z$ coord...

Comment: @SammyBlack I disagree. It's a surface, if you repeat the same curve at every level of z-axis, you get a surface.

Comment: Okay.  I am in place where I can't turn up sound on the video, and I was just looking at the notation (which is ambiguous).  Kindly, disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1):

He's not saying that this holds *everywhere* on the surface: simply that it holds *at the optima*. If the derivative is positive, we could find a small positive value of $s$ such that the corresponding point has $f(Q) > f(P)$ and a small negative value of $s$ such that $f(Q) < f(P)$, therefore $P$ cannot be a local optimum of $f$ restricted to the curve traced out by varying $s$ (and consequently, can't be a local optimum of $f$ restricted to the surface). Similarly if the derivative were negative.

However, if $df/ds = 0$ at $P$, then $P$ *can* be a local optimum. (but it still might not be)

Compare with the one-dimensional version: the optima of a differentiable function on $(a,b)$ can only occur at the points where $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: Hmm, not really, even at the optima, $u$ cannot be any vector tangent to the surface.

Comment: But if you take the intersection of f and g and get a level curve, let's call it C, then along a vector u tangent to C, at the optima, df/ds must be equal to zero.

Comment: There is another question though, $df/ds = dg/ds = 0$, so $\nabla f \perp u$ and $\nabla g \perp u$, but still
this does not mean $\nabla f \parallel \nabla g$, remember this is in a 3D
coordinate system.

Comment: It is indeed true that at any point $P$ on a level curve level curve $f=b$ of $f$ restricted to $g=c$, that $df/ds$ is zero on the tangent to the level curve. That has nothing to do with optima at all. If the derivative in another direction (parallel to $g=c$) is nonzero, that corresponds to increasing/decreasing $b$ having the effect of sliding the curve in one direction or another. If the curve happens to be a local optimum, though, then the derivative in that other direction also has to be zero! Also, the level curve corresponding to an optimum is usually a single point rather than a curve.

Comment: It may help to forget you're in three dimensions: the surface $g=c$ is *just a surface*. The restriction of  $f$ to that surface is simply a function in two dimensions, and you know that in two dimensions, the optima of a function happen where $df = 0$. In the surface-in-three-dimensions picture, the only thing that changes is that directions not parallel to the surface are irrelevant to the optimization problem within the surface.

Comment: Hmm, $\nabla g$ and $\nabla f$ are both two-dimensional vectors in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A proof of Lagrange multiplier taken from here: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-c-lagrange-multipliers-and-constrained-differentials/session-40-proof-of-lagrange-multipliers/MIT18_02SC_notes_22.pdf

[image]